# Laravel Routes - Where clause after group sentence

Tags: laravel, routes, where-clause, wildcard

I'm back here since I'm working with Laravel and Backpack and I'd need to limit the wildcard reaching in order to prevent that catches requests that wouldn't have to catch.

Well, I've the following code:

```
Route::prefix('/{type}/')->group(function() {
    CRUD::resource('members', 'UserCrudController');
})->where('type', '[practice|expert|basic|all]');
```

The fact is that I'm getting the following error:

> Call to a member function where() on null

I know what and why is happening but I don't know how is the way to achieve the expected behavior.

Thank you a lot for the time!

Comment: I don't think you can use `->where` on groups

Comment: Yep, I know that. I'm asking to find a way to achieve that :(